# javascript code to export data to a csv file failing to delimit data by ","

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, internet-explorer-10

**Background Information**

I'm trying to write some javascript / HTML logic that will export some data to a csv format, and open up a new document in Excel or whatever is the default csv app on the workstation.

**Problem**

The code successfully creates a new csv file and prompts to save the file, but when it's displayed in Excel, everything is in one column instead of being split up into multiple columns.

**Code:**

```
function exportTableToCSV($tableName, fileName) {
  var csv = GetCellValues($tableName);
  console.log(csv);
  console.log("filename is:" + fileName);

  if (navigator.userAgent.search("Trident") >= 0) {

    //this is the path that is execute in IE10 browser...
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.write(csv);
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.close();
    window.CsvExpFrame.focus();
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
  } else {
    var uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = uri;
    downloadLink.download = fileName + ".csv";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }
};


function GetCellValues($table) {
           var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = ',',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td, th');

                return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            //csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

    csvData = csv;
  return csvData;
};
```

**CSV File In Excel**

Instead of having 7 columns of data, i have one column of data with all 7 values delimited by comma in it.

**Console Output From Above Code:**

```
   HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
    group_membership_list.html
    "Group Name","PD Number","Dest","Department","First Name","Last Name","ttp"
    "Test Group","45721","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Daniel","Pamplemouse","smtp"
    "Test Group","45721","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Daniel","Pamplemouse","smtp"
    "Test Group","46481","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Benjamin","Grouper","smtp"
    "Test Group","48381","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Gregory","Erock","smtp"
    "Test Group","48381","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Gregory","Erock","smtp"
    "Test Group","48382","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Jonathan","David","smtp"
    "Test Group","48382","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Jonathan","David","smtp"
    "Test Group","45303","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Harold","Cause","smtp"
    "Test Group","45303","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Harold","Cause","smtp"
    "Test Group","45306","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Micah","Latin","smtp"
    filename is:Group Membership List.csv
```

**What I've Tried So far:**

I've tried to change this:

```
 colDelim = ',',
```

to 
     colDelim = '\,',

But that didn't make a difference. 
I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but I can't seem to see my error.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I also tried changing:

```
window.CsvExpFrame.document.write(csv);
```

to this:

```
window.CsvExpFrame.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + csv);
```

based on the following stackoverflow question:
[Javascript/ jQuery : Exporting data in CSV not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185660/javascript-jquery-exporting-data-in-csv-not-working-in-ie)

But it's still a no go.

**EDIT 2**

As a test, I took a copy of the csv file that the web app created, and tried to import it via Excel.  I chose comma as the delimiter.  The end result was that it failed - aka, all the data ends up in one column.
I guess this means the way I'm creating the delimiter in my code is wrong. 
I changed my code to use this:

```
 colDelim = '","',
```

And retried.  It still fails when the file opens via the web app, but if I take that file and manually import it again in Excel, this time it does work.

**Edit 3**

It seems to be related to quotes.  As you can see from the console output, each field there seems to have been properly enclosed in quotes and separated by commas.  But when I examine the data in Excel, the first field (Test Grp) is actually missing the quotes.  It looks like this:

```
  Group Name,"PD Number","Dest","Department","First Name","Last Name","ttp"
  Test Group,"45721","test1@hotmail.com","undefined","Daniel","Pamplemouse","smtp"
```

**EDIT 4**

So I changed my code to look like this:

```
        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '"\,"',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',
```

And now while IE still fails, other browsers like Chrome consistenly work with this combo.  Also, although IE fails to open the file up properly, when I manually import the csv file that the web page generates into Excel, it parses correctly.
Another interesting artifact.  The name of the file that IE generates is

```
Group Membership List_csv.csv
```

whereas Chrome creates:

```
 Group Membership List.csv
```

Comment: Judging by the error message in your log, `window.CsvExpFrame` is undefined or null. Are all relevant scripts or plugins included in your browser?

Comment: @ajm sorry i've updated my post.  that was an old message that has been fixed.

Comment: have you opened the file in notepad or a similar text editor and taken a look at it there?

Comment: Assuming the CSV is correctly generated, Import the data in Excel using the Text Import Wizard and selecting the Delimiter as Comma.

Comment: @Matti Price yes, I've tried to open the generated csv file in Notepad++ and compare it with a csv file that I manually created (and looks good in Excel) but I can't see anything that's different.

Comment: @JavierRey interesting. So the csv looks like its bad because I tried doing what you suggested... take the file created by the web app, and import it as a csv via Excel.  I selected comma as the delimiter.  And the end result is that it all ends up in one column.  Please see EDIT 1

Comment: @JavierRey I meant to say please see Edit 2 for the details

Comment: I'd suggest using something like Diff Checker (https://www.diffchecker.com/) or WinMerge to spot what's changed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the solution, but it is worth trying:

If it only happens using the `SaveAs` option (Trident condition in the question's code), it could be the BOM prefix, missing when the file is saved and possibly required by Excel. You can add it to your CSV text:

```
window.CsvExpFrame.document.write("\uFEFF"+csv);
```

However it could as well be the opposite case, being the BOM prefix added when the file is saved and then not expected by Excel. In this case you might need to remove it with a text editor like Notepad++, encoding and saving the file without BOM.

Comment: I just tried testing this and you've nailed it.  I have to open the file in Notepad++ and change the encoding to remove BOM.  And then when I open in Excel, the file looks normal.  So do you know how I can accomplish this programmatically?

Comment: I'm going to close this question since we've identified the real / root problem.  Created a new / more accurate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760622/how-to-remove-bom-header-from-my-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll post this as an answer:

In your GetCellValues function you're setting your rowDelimeter to be "\r\n".

The first thing I would try is changing it to be just \r\n. I can't say for sure, but the double-quotes may be messing with Excel's import CSV functions.

```
rowDelim = '\r\n';
```

In addition, when I created a similar script to import to excel, I only needed the \n return, didn't need to include \r. You might want to try that if changing the rowDelim doesn't work.

**Edit:**

I found the code I wrote before. Here's what I did:

```
// Create the first row, title, for the CSV
thecsv = "Full Title,CRN,Section,Class,Max,Actual,Open,Start,End,Day,Room\n"; 
// Split an array of info into comma-delimited values where each row is delimited by \n
for(course in courses) {
    for (detail in courses[course]) {
        thecsv += courses[course][detail] + ","
    }
    thecsv += "\n";
}
// Encode the CSV file.
var encodedCSVURI = encodeURIComponent(thecsv);
// Create a link to open the file (in my case, download)
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute("href", "data:attachment/csv," + encodedCSVURI)
link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
var filename = prompt("Please enter a name for the file.", "EXTRACTED_DATA");
link.setAttribute("download", filename + ".csv");
document.body.append(link);
link.click();
```

**Edit 2:**

Here I am encoding the CSV string (which would be your dumped table), creating a link that downloads a file of the encoded CSV string:

```
var encodedCSVURI = encodeURIComponent('some,comma,delimited,string\n,etc,etc,etc,etc'); // Encode the CSV
link.setAttribute("href", "data:attachment/csv," + encodedCSVURI); // Create the download file link with the encoded CSV data
link.setAttribute("download", "filename.csv"); // Here I was prompting the user for a filename, you don't have to
link.setAttribute("target","_blank"); // This is to prevent leaving the current page. You don't have to include this
document.body.append(link); // Add it to the document
link.click(); // Click the link (download the file)
```

Comment: it's definitely related to quotes.  your suggestion however to change my rowDelim didn't work.  I end up with just the heads, and they're all still in one column.

Comment: Please see Edit 3

Comment: I really appreciate the help so far!  And while i normally prefer seeing working code vs a comment about what to try,  your code is pretty different from what I'm doing so I don't know that it's actually helpful.  I'm dumping an HTML table whereas you're creating a string manually and then creating an array.  Also you're creating a link vs. my code that writes to a file.  I've reviewed it but nothing is really jumping out at me.  I'm also suffering from a cold and massive headache so ... i  could be missing something obvious!

Comment: As far as I can tell we're doing the same thing. My code is encoding a CSV file into a download link, and then clicking the link. See Edit 2.

Comment: Does this code work in IE 10 +?  I know that the "encodeURIComponent" messes up the output in IE 10.  Meaning, when it shows up in Excel, all the spaces are %20 etc.  And the ouptut isn't legible. So you'll notice that my code doesn't call that function in the IE10 path.

Comment: I just reviewed everything in this post and went back to the source of things: when opening in Excel, everything appears to be in one column.  I ran it using your export code and got the same problem, which I fixed via Excel. What version of Excel are you running? In my copy of Excel 2016, opening CSV files defaults to tab delimiters (for who knows what reason) and therefore you have to change the import to use comma delimiting.