# how to remove BOM header from my csv file?

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a csv file based on data that shows up in a table on my web page.

**Problem**

Every time I would trigger the "save to csv" function, the file would open up in Excel but it wouldn't parse out the individual fields (using a comma separator).  Everything would always appear in one column.  It would properly break out the different lines. 
After much testing / troubleshooting and help from stackoverflow, ends up that my real issue is that a BOM header is being added and seems to be messing it up.  When I open the csv file in Notepad++ and change the encoding to remove the BOM header and then I reopen the file in Excel, it looks just fine.

**Code**

This is what the code looks like: (note: the non IE path works just fine. )

```
function exportTableToCSV($tableName, fileName) {
  var csv = GetCellValues($tableName);
  console.log(csv);
  console.log("filename is:" + fileName);

  if (navigator.userAgent.search("Trident") >= 0) {

    //this is the path that is execute in IE10 browser...
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.write(csv);
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.close();
    window.CsvExpFrame.focus();
    window.CsvExpFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
  } else {
    var uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(csv);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = uri;
    downloadLink.download = fileName + ".csv";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  }
};
```

**Question**

How can I programatically remove the BOM header?

**What I've Tried So Far**

So far, I've tried the following code changes:

1. Tried to change / specify the encoding like so:  (all the lines are commented out here... but I cycled through each one and retried the export)

   //window.CsvExpFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
   //window.CsvExpFrame.document.open('data:text/csv;windows-1252; ')
   //window.CsvExpFrame.document.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8; ')
   //window.CsvExpFrame.document.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,')
2. Tried to remove the header like so:

   //csv = csv.replace(/\uFFFD/g, '')
     csv = csv.replace(/\uFEFF/g, '')
     window.CsvExpFrame.document.write(csv);

So far, nothing has worked.  If you have any suggestions for me I'd appreciate it.  I've been reading through other similar posts on stackoverflow and trying them but so far it's a no go.  I havent' found one that's javascript specific..

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Since posting this question, I've discovered some additional / helpful artifacts:

When I open the file in Notepad++, the encoding is set to "UCS-2 LE BOM".
I've noticed that saving the file as:

```
  "UTF-8 BOM" fixes the issue.
  "UTF-8" (aka no BOM) fixes the issue
  "UCS-2 BE BOM"  almost works but it adds some funky characters the first field's header, so it looks like this: 

   þÿ"Group Name"
```

I tried to change my code to explicitly add the BOM header like so:

```
window.CsvExpFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
window.CsvExpFrame.document.write("\uFEFF"+csv); // ADD BOM 
//window.CsvExpFrame.document.write(csv);
window.CsvExpFrame.document.close();
window.CsvExpFrame.focus();
window.CsvExpFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
```

But as per Notepad++, this code didn't change the encoding. It's still set to LE BOM.
Lastly, I created 2 versions of this csv file.  Both were generated by the web application.  But for the second file, I used Notepad++ to change the encoding to one that works.  Then I used "Meld" to try to do a diff on the two files but they appear as being identical.

**EDIT 2**

If I change the logic so that there is no conditional check for IE trident but the code just always does this:

```
function exportTableToCSV($tableName, fileName) {
  var csv = GetCellValues($tableName);
  console.log(csv);
  console.log("filename is:" + fileName);
    var uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = uri;
    downloadLink.download = fileName + ".csv";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

IE bombs with the following error:

SCRIPT122: The data area passed to a system call is too small.

And it's failing on the "downloadLink.click();" call.

Comment: Just a question, why not forget the 'Trident' case and use the other approach, it is a good and safe way, and probably applicable also if the browser is IE Trident.

Comment: @JavierRey it's a good suggestion you make.  But it fails with an error.  Please see Edit 2

Comment: Oh yes, it is not as good approach as I thought. The link URL size is limited in browsers, 2080 in IE, more in others, but still too small for big CSV strings. I'll try to find a workaround for this downloading limit problem and come back here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I think, converting the CSV `String` to `Blob`, then to `ObjectURL`, and, for IE10+, using `navigator.msSaveBlob`:

```
function exportCSV(csv, filename) {
  if (!filename) {filename = 'export.csv';}
  var blob = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
  if (!navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
  } else {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename); // IE 10+
  }
}
```

Following your implementation:

```
function exportTableToCSV($tableName, fileName) {
  var csv = GetCellValues($tableName); console.log(fileName, csv);
  exportCSV(csv, fileName);
}
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, with several thousands of lines.

Comment: Works perfect.  Thanks very much