# how to export table to excel using jquery Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, internet-explorer

I want to export table to excel using jquery in Internet Explorer all the scripts i have seen they works on Chrome and Mozilla but i want a code that works on Internet Explorer.

and my Script is this.

```
exportExcel : (function() {

var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
   , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
   , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
   , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

    return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Comment: what version of IE is this not working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tableToExcel jQuery throws strange error in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619902/tabletoexcel-jquery-throws-strange-error-in-ie)

Comment: it is not working in IE 11

Comment: I have seen that solution but it does not work out for me...