# How to export Datatables table to Excel which works in IE as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I am using

```
  var tableToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function(s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }
        , format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };
        return function(table, fileName) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {
                worksheet: fileName || 'Worksheet', 
                table: table.innerHTML
            }
            $("<a id='dlink'  style='display:none;'></a>").appendTo("body");
                document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                document.getElementById("dlink").download = fileName;
                document.getElementById("dlink").click();
        }
    })();
```

for exporting datatables to excel and it works fine in both chrome and firefox. however it gives

> **The data area passed to a system call is too small.**

error in **all IE versions**. Please give me some workaround as how to solve this problem or suggest any new method that works in all browsers. I am googling about the same since yesterday but all in vain...
Any help would be apperciated .. thanks

:Edit i have tried downloadify.js, filesaver but didn't worked for me .

Comment: Duplicate of [tabletoexcel-jquery-throws-strange-error-in-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619902/tabletoexcel-jquery-throws-strange-error-in-ie)

Comment: Yes,I have seen that question but couldn't get any result. That's why i posted here.

Comment: Like the link states, the error is due a limitation in how IE stores URIs (ie. old versions have a limited data capacity). If you need to support old IE versions, then you'll have to do this the old way and create the Excel server side.

Comment: Yes, now i am using downloadify for server side downloading. also The code above is not supported in any IE versions ..I am using IE 11...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jspdf to get the desired results.Following points i achieved:-

```
1) This works in all versions of IE.
2) You can give the freeze column and freeze row options also in Excel
```

.

**Libraries I used**

```
1)downloadify.js 
2)swfobject.js
3)downloadify.swf
```

**Functions i used**

```
1)getHtmlForExport(); // gives the html of the table to be exported.
2)tableToExcel();// converts html code to Microsoft Excel specific XML code
3)handleExcelExport();// downloads excel specific XML to excel file.


var tableToExcel = function (table, horizontalFreezeRowNo, VerticalFreezeRowNo) {
    var worksheetString = '';
    //worksheet freeze pane options 
    worksheetString += '<x:WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"><x:Selected/><x:FreezePanes/><x:FrozenNoSplit/><x:ActivePane>2</x:ActivePane>';
    if (horizontalFreezeRowNo !== undefined)
        worksheetString += '<x:SplitHorizontal>' + horizontalFreezeRowNo + '</x:SplitHorizontal><x:TopRowBottomPane>' + horizontalFreezeRowNo + '</x:TopRowBottomPane>';
    if (VerticalFreezeRowNo !== undefined)
        worksheetString += '<x:SplitVertical>' + VerticalFreezeRowNo + '</x:SplitVertical><x:LeftColumnRightPane>' + VerticalFreezeRowNo + '</x:LeftColumnRightPane>';

    worksheetString += '</x:WorksheetOptions>';

    var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>' + worksheetString + '</x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'

    , format = function (s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
            return c[p];
        })
    };
    if (!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {
        table: table.innerHTML
    }
    $("#exportTable").remove();
    return format(template, ctx)
}

function handleExcelExport(gridConfig) {
    $("." + gridConfig.objectID + "Export").downloadify({
        filename: function () {
            var elementClicked = this.el;
            var headerText = $(elementClicked).parents('.portlet').find('.portlet-title h8').text();
            var fileName;
            if (elementClicked == undefined || headerText == undefined) {
                fileName = "excel"
            } else {
                fileName = headerText.toString().trim()
            }
            return fileName + ".xls";
        },
        data: function () {
            var elementClicked = this.el;

            getHtmlForExport(elementClicked, gridConfig);
            return (tableToExcel('exportTable', 1, 1));// table id, horizontal freeze,vertical freeze 
        },
        onComplete: function () {

        },
        onCancel: function () {

        },
        onError: function () {

        },
        swf: 'resources/js/downloadify/downloadify.swf',
        downloadImage: 'resources/css/images/excelDownload.png',
        width: 65,
        height: 20,
        transparent: true,
        append: false
    });
}
```

and for **getHtmlForExport** you have to write the logic to get the html of table you want to export .