# Export HTML Table to Excel with ID or class tags in the table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

I have a table in HTML on my webpage, and when using JQuery to export it to Excel, it will not work if I have any id or class tags in the table header.

the JQuery i am using is

```
//wont work unless the table has no class or id
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $("#tableForExcel").html());
e.preventDefault();
});
```

The table I am using is

```
<table id='SearchTable' class='table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table blue '>
<tr>
<th class='ReportManager'>Report Manager</th>
<th class='ReportDetail'>Report Detail</th>
<th class='Form'>Form</th>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class='ReportManager'></td>
<td class='ReportDetail'></td>
<td class='Form'></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class='ReportManager'></td>
<td class='ReportDetail'></td>
<td class='Form'></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

I would be grateful if you could help me \ show me how i should adjust my code to get this to export.

Comment: You are not technically using jQuery to do the export -- the `window.open` piece is just plain JavaScript. The `data:` protocol is handled by your browser and OS. The only thing jQuery is doing here is grabbing the table HTML. If the class names are causing issues, you could clone the table, remove the classes, and pass that along instead.

Comment: If i remove all the tags, using the javascript how would i be able to identify how to put them back after the export so that table still looks the same after export?

Comment: Well, Excel wasn't built to be an HTML/CSS parser. It knows nothing about your Bootstrap class names. IMHO, if you want "pretty" Excel output, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: i dont need pretty, i just need to export it to excel, but with the tags it just gives me the HTML in an excel cell,  without any tags it exports fine

Comment: What happens if you use the proper double-quotations in your markup instead of single-quotes? Excel, like most Microsoft products, likely needs absolutely perfect markup, so the single-quotes could be throwing it off. (i.e. replace all `'` with `"`).

Comment: still gives me the same result of the HTML in cell A1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89399/discussion-between-simon-price-and-c).

Comment: Maybe look into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297238/74757.

Comment: I will take a look at this shortly, sorry for the long delay in getting back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem this way:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' +'<table>' +$("#SearchTable").html()+ '</table>');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The project has passes now, but will try this anyway and let you know as this will crop up again I am sure.

Comment: I supposed so, but I've decided to post the answer because I've found any solution for this problem and I think it could be useful for another users. :)

Comment: it doesn't export it, it just throws the `data:application/vnd.ms-excel,<table><tbody><tr><th class="ReportManager">Report Manager</th><th class="ReportDetail">Report Detail</th><th class="Form">Form</th></tr><tr><td class="ReportManager">1</td><td class="ReportDetail">2</td><td class="Form">3</td></tr><tr><td class="ReportManager">4</td><td class="ReportDetail">5</td><td class="Form">6</td></tr></tbody></table>` into the address bar and that's it

Comment: to be fair that could be an environment issue here at my office, im forced to use IE now, will try it on chrome later