# Export the html table to csv

Tags: javascript, csv, printing, html-table, export-to-csv

I have a sample [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3jj/9/) where i can print the html table to pdf format as,

```
function printpage() {
    var data = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="4">Sample Report</td></tr>' + document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML + '</table>';
    data += '<br/><button onclick="window.print()"  class="noprint">Print the Report</button>';
    data += '<style type="text/css" media="print"> .noprint {visibility: hidden;} </style>';
    myWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
    myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
    myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
    myWindow.screenX = 0;
    myWindow.screenY = 0;
    myWindow.document.write(data);
    myWindow.document.close();
    myWindow.focus();
}
```

how can i add one more button inside the print preview page using which i can export the same table in csv/xls format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link . You will get the solution

```
  `http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/`
```

Comment: Unable to download header row

Comment: Code is written for only table row. not for headers. You can see line number 3 
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

Comment: How to give other name to the downloaded file than `download`?