# Export Table to Excel using jQuery

Tags: jquery, excel

I have an html page in which there is a table and i want to export the table data to Excel file.

I used the following code:

```
<head>
<title>Email application</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#BtnSendMessage").click(function(e) {            
        window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#TblExport').html()));            
        e.preventDefault();            
    })    </script></head>
```

My Html Page:

```
<body>    
<table id="TblExport">
    <tr>            
        <td><input type="text" id="TxtName" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="TxtEmail" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <textarea id="TxtMessage"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="BtnSendMessage" value="SendMessage" /></td>
        <td><label id="LblErrorMessage"></label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, after clicking on the button nothing is happening..

Comment: Would be helpful if you could set up a jsfiddle. :)

Comment: Have you included the references to the script to call btechco_excelexport?

Comment: On a high level `$datatype` is undefined. i.e. you have missed some js file. What is `btechco_excelexport`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/dE7AV/ - i have created a fiddle. I can see that an excel file is getting opened with the html. What is that you are expecting?

Comment: @SherinMathew i need to store only values inserted on that textboxes.

Comment: Please refer the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html/16203218#16203218. Kindly let us know if you still need assistance.