# javascript find html <tr> with class and with nested <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

running simple export javscript function for this stackoverflow - [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/

however I want to change it up so it only gets rows that have a certain class, this is what i've tried so far.

original

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),
```

mine

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr.hasClass('show'):has(td)'),
```

I know nothing about JS, apparently, so help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `hasClass` in selector. Your code should be:

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr.show:has(td)'),
```

where your class name is `show`. Dot (`.`) in jQuery and CSS means `class` selector already.