# Node JS fs module inside browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, requirejs, browserify

I have a scenario where I want to export data to CSV from the client-side. I will have a textbox/area or whatever where the user can input data and then ideally with one click, a local CSV file will be updated with that data.

This is easily achievable with NodeJS with server interaction, and its core modules (specifically `fs` module), but apparently not so much from a browser.

I found out that certain node modules (for example `underscore`), support RequireJS's method of making a particular module work in the browser. So for underscore I did this:

**methods.js**

```
define(['underscore'],function(_) {

    var Methods = {
        doSomething: function() {

            var x = _.size({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, xuz: 3});

            alert(x);
        }
    };

    return Methods;
});
```

**common.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseURL: 'node_modules',
    paths: {
        underscore: 'underscore/underscore',
    }
});

require(['methods'], function(y){
    y.doSomething();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script data-main="common" src="require.js"></script>
<script>
require(['common'], function() {

    require(['methods.js']);
});
</script>
```

The above works fine and will show an alert: 4.

But when I try the same with the `fs` module it won't work. It will show this error:

```
Module name "util" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

As far as I can understand, this is because `fs` requires several other modules, one of them being `util`.

So I proceeded to add all these modules to the RequireJS config. But still no luck, so I specifically tested `util` module by itself as this doesn't seem to require other modules to work.

And now I am stuck on this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

I tried modularizing this `util` module by encapsulating the whole module source code in this:

```
define([], function() {})
```

But it didn't work either... I've also tried copying `underscore`'s model but still no luck.

So I was wondering if anyone managed to use `util` & `fs` modules (or any other core NodeJS modules) within the browser with libraries such as RequireJS or Browserify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's right, `exports` is node-specific JS (used to make part of your module available outside the module) and isn't supported by web-browsers. Even though NodeJS is technically JS, there are client specific properties (like the `window` property for browsers, and `exports` for NodeJS apps) that can't be interchanged.

That said, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html) a client side JS answer to the CSV problem.

Comment: Both answers that I received are correct, as I have also found out after more research. What I ended up doing for my specific scenario though (to keep everything away from databases & possibly client-side for the user) is having two NodeJS servers running (one for read & other for write). These listen for CSV file changes and will write/read from/to the file system through NodeJS fs module that way. This approach is not totally client-side, but you avoid DB interaction & maintenance plus everything is in JS from client to server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet (and probably only one) is to use [HTML5 FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/). I am not aware of any other browser feature that would allow to work with files on client computer except maybe Flash and similar solution.

I am bit confused by your browserify tag since you are not obviously using Browserify. That would fix your issue with "exports is not defined".

Comment: It is also possible to emulate `fs` in the browser using [`filer`](https://github.com/filerjs/filer), which uses `IndexedDB` to simulate a filesystem.