# Angular 8 - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in

Tags: angular, node-modules

When I try to use

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
```

I get the error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

In fact, when I use `readFileSync` in my program in VS even the intellisense works fine, but when I run `ng serve` it comes up with a compiler error.

I've spent hours looking at other SO posts and searching the internet. Nothing has worked. For example, have tried setting `"types": ["node"]` where previously it was empty. Have tried using a strange `///` syntax for importing, but that didn't work either.

I've also tried strange syntax like `import { fs } from '@types/node';`.

I'm using fs for the following `socket.io` call:

```
this.socket = io('https://12.123.1245:1234', { ca: readFileSync('./assets/cert.pem'), rejectUnauthorized: false });
```

Comment: and what is `fs`?

Comment: Are you trying to [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656426/angular-7-how-to-use-fs-module)? In which case you need to read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656426/angular-7-how-to-use-fs-module#comment94171732_53656426)

Comment: Yeah thanks @SagarChaudhary, obviously it's an npm package, which one...

Comment: I thought you didnt knew. Not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fs is a nodeJs only module. When you run "ng serve" your app will be compiled and run in your browser, so you can not use this mode. To read from a file without user action ( select file ) is not possible for security reason on your browser

Comment: what if user provides consent. You would still need fs module to read file.

Comment: You need to use the browser file api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File