# Saving CSV file using blob in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, safari

I have codes below to generate the download link so that users could download the  .csv file on my site.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.id = "csvDwnLink";
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var csv = "\ufeff" + CSV,
    blob = new window.Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv, charset=UTF-8'}),
    csvUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    filename = 'export.csv';

$("#csvDwnLink").attr({'download': filename, 'href': csvUrl});
$('#csvDwnLink')[0].click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

I hope the user could click the download link with `csvUrl` to download the cvs file.
It works on chrome. However, when I click the same link using Safari, it will directly show me the content of the csv file in the tab.

How do I solve this problem so that the safari will show the saving file window which user could select the path where they want to save the file instead of showing the content of the cvs file directly when I click the download link?
Hope someone could me some recommendations or alternative methods.
Thanks in advance!

**== Updated ==**
Find out solutions here
[solution 1](https://adilapapaya.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/exporting-data-from-a-web-browser-to-a-csv-file-using-javascript/), 
[solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

The code will be:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.id = "csvDwnLink";

document.body.appendChild(link);
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var csv = "\ufeff" + CSV,
    csvData = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv),
    filename = 'filename.csv';
$("#csvDwnLink").attr({'download': filename, 'href': csvData});
$('#csvDwnLink')[0].click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

Safari will download the file for the user, however, the file name will be `unknown`, probably it's because Safari don't support 'download' attribute yet as `raphael` mentioned.

Comment: How does the HTML look (especially the link that gets `csvUrl` as href)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the code snippet. I create the link element in JS and set the attribute including **csvUrl** to that download link directly.

Comment: I created a JSFiddle for your question: http://jsfiddle.net/628mmkww/2/ - it looks like Safari does not support what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did a quick research - I looks like Safari does not support what you are trying to achieve.

The reason why your solution works in Chrome (and Firefox) is that they [support the download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) - Safari doesn't yet.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: And it seems that it won't be fixed in the near future: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102914
Someone with webkit skills around to write a patch?

Answer (score 0):

Safari 10.1+ supports "download" attribute. It should work now.

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/129#issuecomment-275221240

Comment: however Safari IOS still doesnt support this