# Cannot download pdf file in Safari using javascript FileSaver.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, pdf.js, filesaver.js

I have an app it has pdf viewer (used mozilla pdf) and downloading capability(using FileSaver.js). After clicking the download button that pdf file has been downloaded.
But in Safari downloads file like "unknown". How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving cvs file using blob in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799696/saving-cvs-file-using-blob-in-safari)

Comment: In FileSaver.js, downloads file with "unknown" name in safari.

Do you know how to handle this?

Comment: No, unfortunately you are correct, I don't have a proper workaround. Deleting my comment.