# How can I export to csv using jquery as multiple sheets in the same excel file?

Tags: jquery, excel, csv

I am using the solution mentioned here: 
[Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html?answertab=active#tab-top)

The fiddle for this is: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/

I will be calling the function exportTableToCSV multiple times as I have three tables per category (Category1 has three tables, Category2 has three tables and CAtegory3 has three tables).

What I want is a separate sheet in the same excel file per category.

How do I need to change the following code here to be able to create three sheets in the same excel file - Category 1, 2 and 3?

```
$(this).attr({
                                'download': 'export.csv',
                                'href': csvData,
                                'target': '_blank'
                            });
```

I have implemented all 6 tables in one sheet right now. If I can figure this one out with this method, it will be great!

Comment: csv doesn't have sheets, you will need to use an excel library

Comment: Since I am able to download it as an excel sheet, I was wondering there would be some way to create sheets in it as well.