# html table to CSV via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I have an issue where I'm trying to export html table to a csv file. The issue is that no download box appears but I know my JS function is run via an alert check.

I wonder if it can be my table that is generated from an exiting csv file like this:

```
  echo "<table>\n\n";
  $f = fopen("../translations/EXAMPLE.csv", "r");
  while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td contenteditable>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  fclose($f);
  echo "\n</table>";
```

I have a button to call the javascript:

```
<button class='saveCSV' style='float:right;'>Save</button>
```

And here is the javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '","',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
                alert("KØRT");
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".saveCSV").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

Anyone having an idea to what os wrong here and the csv file is not exported?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Does `console.log(csv)` (before the csvData line) produce anything? My point is: at what point is the script failing. Does it give you your CSV data, but just doesn't offer it as a 'download'?

Comment: If I apply console.log(csv) right after csvData line I get the table as csv in the console. Before the csvData line i get nothing.

Comment: @shennan - So I get the csv in console.log but how can it not download or sent the popup message ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply convert the csvData to a blob file or base64 file and then send to the server using ajax. Take note of the two functions added after the document.ready.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
        var byteString;
        if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
            byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
        else
            byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

        // separate out the mime component
        var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

        // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
        var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
    }

function uploadCSV( blob ) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var fd = {};
    fd["fname"] = "example.csv";
    fd["data"] = event.target.result;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'upload.php',
      data: fd,
      dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
        function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

            var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

                // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
                // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
                tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
                tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

                // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
                colDelim = '","',
                rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

                // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
                csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                    var $row = $(row),
                        $cols = $row.find('td');

                    return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                        var $col = $(col),
                            text = $col.text();

                        return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

                    }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

                }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                    .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                    .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

                // Data URI
                csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

            var asblob = dataURItoBlob(csvData);
            uploadCSV( asblob ); //prepare and send via ajax post. The ajax post is not tested though

        }

        // This must be a hyperlink
        $(".saveCSV").on('click', function (event) {
            // CSV
            exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

            // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
            // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
        });
    });
```

PHP CODE should be

```
<?
// pull the raw binary data from the POST array
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
// decode it
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
// print out the raw data,
$filename = $_POST['fname'];
echo $filename;
// write the data out to the file
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

OR

```
Blob blob = *// get Blob file *
byte [] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Testing/";
File dir = new File(filePath);
File file = new File(dir, "filename.csv");
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
//bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

Comment: this works. Only how do I decide where the csv file is saved on the server?

Comment: Thats up to you to decide using PHP. Create a folder on your server and save the file. the php code above may not match your requirement. Just do what you want from the data received

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `encodeURIComponent` method? With some initial testing, I found this to break functionality. So your code may look something like this instead:

```
var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
```

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/2vLtawmv/) of this in action.

Remember also, that what you're attempting to do won't work in every browser as the `download` attribute is not universally supported. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for more about support.