# export data to csv with multiple sheets through javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

Is it possible to generate a CSV with multiple data?
I have 2 tabs in which different type of question like general and advanced. After filling the form i want the export the data to one csv file with 2 Sheets.
e.g. mydata.csv will be the file name and two sheets of general and advanced information.

Comment: Not sure I well understood : do you know that a csv file is a plain text file which can't have sheets (even if it can be opened by spreadsheet applications) ?

Comment: you can have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/kpegu/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

Comment: I am not asking to export data to single file with single sheet. i am asking for multiple sheets in a single csv @KunalKakkad

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteRudant: Thanx...it means i can not have multiple sheets in a single csv.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using below code

```
function concatCSVAndOutput(csvFilePaths, outputFilePath) {
const promises = csvFilePaths.map((path) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const dataArray = [];
    return csv
        .parseFile(path, {headers: true})
        .on('data', function(data) {
            dataArray.push(data);
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            resolve(dataArray);
        });
    });
});

return Promise.all(promises)
    .then((results) => {

        const csvStream = csv.format({headers: true});
        const writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath);

        writableStream.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('DONE!');
        });

        csvStream.pipe(writableStream);
        results.forEach((result) => {
        result.forEach((data) => {
            csvStream.write(data);
        });
        });
        csvStream.end();

    });
    }

concatCSVAndOutput(['1.csv', '2.csv'], 'outputfile.csv');
```