# Export to CSV using jQuery and html recursively get css :before content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, csv

This is a question based on an answer to another question.

Please see this:

[Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html/16203218#tab-top)

Regarding the code `text = $col.text();` if there is a CSS :before content, I get `text = " "`, because the cell is

```
<td><div id="state" class="state-c"> </div></td>
```

but actually the generated HTML shows a string in that cell because of the CSS style:

```
.state-c:before {
    content: "Confirmed";
}
```

I tried with:

```
text = $col.text();
if (text.length < 2) { // text.length is always longer than 2 except when is = " "
    text = window.getComputedStyle($('#state')[0], ':before').content;
}
```

and many variations of this code like  `window.getComputedStyle($(col)[0], ':before').content;`, etc, but I can't find a way to make it work inside that code, while it works perfectly in other contexts.

Is it possible to get the the string of the CSS :before content in this described way?