# How to download the html table datas in xlsx format using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery, xlsx

here i have one html table i want to do download the datas in xls format,i don't know to download,i want to use any plugin or not,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="ReportTable" class="myClass">
    <tr bgcolor="#CCC">
      <td width="100">id</td>
      <td width="700">Name</td>
      <td width="170">Email</td>
      <td width="30">Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kani</td>
      <td>Kani@gmail.com</td>
      <td>9986128665</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<input type="submit" value="Export to Excel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [Export to CSV using jQuery and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078544/export-to-csv-using-jquery-and-html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

      // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
      // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
      tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
      tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

      // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
      colDelim = '","',
      rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

      // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
      csv = '"' + $rows.map(function(i, row) {
        var $row = $(row),
          $cols = $row.find('td');

        return $cols.map(function(j, col) {
          var $col = $(col),
            text = $col.text();

          return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

        }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

      }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
      .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
      .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';

    // Deliberate 'false', see comment below
    if (false && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {

      var blob = new Blob([decodeURIComponent(csv)], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf8'
      });

      // Crashes in IE 10, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge
      // See MS Edge Issue #10396033
      // Hence, the deliberate 'false'
      // This is here just for completeness
      // Remove the 'false' at your own risk
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);

    } else if (window.Blob && window.URL) {
      // HTML5 Blob        
      var blob = new Blob([csv], {
        type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'
      });
      var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvUrl
        });
    } else {
      // Data URI
      var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

      $(this)
        .attr({
          'download': filename,
          'href': csvData,
          'target': '_blank'
        });
    }
  }

  // This must be a hyperlink
  $(".export").on('click', function(event) {
    // CSV
    var args = [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv'];

    exportTableToCSV.apply(this, args);

    // If CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
    // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
  });
});
```

```css
a.export,
a.export:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="export">Export Table data into Excel</a>
<div id="dvData">
    <table border="1" id="ReportTable" class="myClass">
    <tr bgcolor="#CCC">
      <td width="100">id</td>
      <td width="700">Name</td>
      <td width="170">Email</td>
      <td width="30">Mobile</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Kani</td>
      <td>Kani@gmail.com</td>
      <td>9986128665</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```