# How to export table from HTML to Excel and arrange images in cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, export-to-excel

I need to export table from HTML to Excel.

My table consists of Name, Age, Date, Amount and Image column with small image.

I have a function that generates an excel document:

```js
function downloadsalesreport() {
    var cache = {};

    this.tmpl = function tmpl(str, data) {
        // Figure out if we're getting a template, or if we need to
        // load the template - and be sure to cache the result.
        var fn = !/\W/.test(str)
            ? cache[str] = cache[str] || tmpl(document.getElementById(str).innerHTML)

            // Generate a reusable function that will serve as a template
            // generator (and which will be cached).
            : new Function(
                "obj",
                "var p=[],print=function(){p.push.apply(p,arguments);};"
                // Introduce the data as local variables using with(){}
                + "with(obj){p.push('"
                // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
                + str.replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
                    .split("{{").join("\t")
                    .replace(/((^|}})[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")
                    .replace(/\t=(.*?)}}/g, "',$1,'")
                    .split("\t").join("');")
                    .split("}}").join("p.push('")
                    .split("\r").join("\\'")
                + "');}return p.join('');"
            );

        // Provide some basic currying to the user
        return data ? fn(data) : fn;
    };


    var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{{=worksheet}}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body>{{for(var i=0; i<tables.length;i++){ }}<table>{{=tables[i]}}</table>{{ } }}</body></html>',
            base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
            format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (tableList, name) {
            if (!tableList.length > 0 && !tableList[0].nodeType) table = document.getElementById("#tablesalesentry")
            var tables = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < tableList.length; i++) { tables.push(tableList[i].innerHTML); }
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', tables: tables };
            window.location.href = uri + base64(tmpl(template, ctx))
        }
    })();

    tableToExcel(document.getElementsByTagName("table"), "one");

}
```

It works perfectly but my problem is in Excel: **images are not aligned properly**.

In Excel cells which consists of images are collapsed but remaining data (Name, Age, Date, Amount) are perfectly arranged.

Please suggest me any idea regarding export table to excel.

Comment: nice code thank you!
how to change the filename and add the .xls extensions?

Comment: Does this work in IE?